# How to get the last row from DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I hava a DataFrame,the DataFrame hava two column 'value' and 'timestamp',,the 'timestmp' is ordered,I want to get the last row of the DataFrame,what should I do?

this is my input:

```
+-----+---------+
|value|timestamp|
+-----+---------+
|    1|        1|
|    4|        2|
|    3|        3|
|    2|        4|
|    5|        5|
|    7|        6|
|    3|        7|
|    5|        8|
|    4|        9|
|   18|       10|
+-----+---------+
```

this is my code:

```
    val arr = Array((1,1),(4,2),(3,3),(2,4),(5,5),(7,6),(3,7),(5,8),(4,9),(18,10))
    var df=m_sparkCtx.parallelize(arr).toDF("value","timestamp")
```

this is my expected result:

```
+-----+---------+
|value|timestamp|
+-----+---------+
|   18|       10|
+-----+---------+
```

Comment: Would `df.where($"timestamp" === max($"timestamp")` work?

Comment: It doesnot work Exchange rangepartitioning(ts#7 ASC NULLS FIRST, 200)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd simply `reduce`:

```
df.reduce { (x, y) => 
  if (x.getAs[Int]("timestamp") > y.getAs[Int]("timestamp")) x else y 
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this, it works for me.

```
df.orderBy($"value".desc).show(1)
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use simply the query that
- orders your table by descending order 
- takes 1st value from this order

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("table_df")
query_latest_rec = """SELECT * FROM table_df ORDER BY value DESC limit 1"""
latest_rec = self.sqlContext.sql(query_latest_rec)
latest_rec.show()
```

Comment: I'm using this solution, it's the obvious one.

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient way is to `reduce` your DataFrame. This gives you a single row which you can convert back to a DataFrame, but as it contains only 1 record, this does not make much sense.

```
sparkContext.parallelize(
  Seq(
  df.reduce {
    (a, b) => if (a.getAs[Int]("timestamp") > b.getAs[Int]("timestamp")) a else b 
   } match {case Row(value:Int,timestamp:Int) => (value,timestamp)}
  )
)
.toDF("value","timestamp")
.show


+-----+---------+
|value|timestamp|
+-----+---------+
|   18|       10|
+-----+---------+
```

Less efficient (as it needs shuffling) although shorter is this solution:

```
df
.where($"timestamp" === df.groupBy().agg(max($"timestamp")).map(_.getInt(0)).collect.head)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your timestamp column is unique and is in increasing order then there are following ways to get the last row

```
println(df.sort($"timestamp", $"timestamp".desc).first())

// Output [1,1]

df.sort($"timestamp", $"timestamp".desc).take(1).foreach(println)

// Output [1,1]

df.where($"timestamp" === df.count()).show
```

Output:

```
+-----+---------+
|value|timestamp|
+-----+---------+
|   18|       10|
+-----+---------+
```

If not create a new column with the index and select the last index as below

```
val df1 = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    df.rdd.zipWithIndex.map {
  case (row, index) => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq :+ index)
},
StructType(df.schema.fields :+ StructField("index", LongType, false)))

df1.where($"timestamp" === df.count()).drop("index").show
```

Output:

```
+-----+---------+
|value|timestamp|
+-----+---------+
|   18|       10|
+-----+---------+
```

Comment: sort function is inefficient,I donnot want to use sort function

Comment: than you can use df.where($"timestamp" === df.count())

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this function [desc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#desc(java.lang.String)): `Column desc(String columnName)`

```
df.orderBy(desc("value")).show(1)
```

which gives same result as

```
df.orderBy($"value".desc).show(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Java:

```
Dataset<Row> sortDF = inputDF.orderBy(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col(config.getIncrementingColumn()).desc());
Row row = sortDF.first()
```